# Parameterized imports in typescript angular

Tags: typescript

Is parameterized imports available in typescript? I am trying to do the following:

1. In my environments file I have specified the program.
2. I want to import file/components in my angular module based on the program which is active like the following:

```
/* 
The idea here is that I have a component in two different folders example:

 - /root/components/page-not-found/bingo/page-not-found-component.ts
 - /root/components/page-not-found/pepsi/page-not-found-component.ts
In my environment file I can specify the program as 'bingo' or 'pepsi' which are the folder names and I want to load the component either from 'bingo' directory or from the 'pepsi' directory.
*/

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } `./root/components/page-not-found/${environment.program}/page-not-found-component`; // here environment.program refers to the folder name.

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ]
});
```

I tried with the following but no success:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PageNotFoundComponent: (() => import(`./root/components/page-not-found/${environment.program}/page-not-found-component`).then((m) => m.PageNotFoundComponent))()
  ]
});
```

Is there something using javascript/typescript I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but I have a suggestion for a different approach.

I think you can create an `*if` block inside your component, and load the desired `PageNotFoundComopnent` based on the environment from there.

PageNotFoundComoponent html

```
<page-not-found-component-dev *ngIf="mode==='dev'"></page-not-found-component-dev>
<page-not-found-component-prod *ngIf="mode==='prod'"></page-not-found-component-dev>
```

PageNotFoundComoponent ts

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { PageNotFoundComponentDev } `./root/components/page-not-found-dev/page-not-found-component-dev`;
import { PageNotFoundComponentProd } `./root/components/page-not-found-prod/page-not-found-component-prod`;

@Component({
...
})
export class PageNotFoundComoponent {

 mode = 'dev';
 constructor(){
  mode = environment.mode;
 }

}
```

Comment: Hey John, thanks for looking into this, the solution you proposed is not what I am looking for, I have made the changes in the question statement hope that works for you. Thanks!